# Hsqldb errors during SchemaExport using Hibernate 4.1

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, hsqldb, schemaexport

How do I get rid of these errors below when running Hibernate's SchemaExport? It doesn't seem to cause a problem actually - my tests still run just fine - but I don't like seeing the errors and having to scroll down a lot just to see what went wrong with a test.

Is there any way to get rid of them - by either solving the error or just making it quiet?

```
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:425 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table click drop constraint FK5A5C588CBB8DB5
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:426 - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.CLICK
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:425 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table click drop constraint FK5A5C5885AC11C60
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:426 - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.CLICK
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:425 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table click drop constraint FK5A5C58841979673
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:426 - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.CLICK
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:425 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table click drop constraint FK5A5C588430DFF29
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:426 - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.CLICK
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:425 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table click drop constraint FK5A5C588B6909BE1
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:426 - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.CLICK
17:28:19 ERROR SchemaExport:425 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table comment drop constraint FK38A5EE5FCBB8DB5
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just don't use 2.2.x series of hsqldb. 2.0.0 is fine.

Comment: 2.0 has other problems and may not be an option. Why doesn't 2.2.x work?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of HsqlDB you are using? I am using 2.2.9 with hibernate 4.1.3. I see no errors.. you could try this version, with user SA.

Or you could try grant permissions for your PUBLIC both on table and the sequence it is using

Comment: I am using 2.2.8 with Hibernate 4.1.3. Are you sure that you don't have your log turned off?

Comment: I think the 2.2.x series of HSQLDB is buggy. I just recently discovered a massive performance problem. If you try with 2.0.0, you'll notice a massive performance gain (like 1000% better). The error messages have died down. I think I'm going to stick with 2.0.0.

Comment: good that the erros are gone with 2.0.*. I have checked, no such errors, the constraints are dropped without error messages.. btw, I am using JPA EntityManager. - Maddy